# My sql update statement is not filling my column

Tags: sql, left-join, sybase, unique-key

I have two tables A and B.

**Table A**  has columns:
LI
PC (key)
 
CI (key)
 
DI
TM
V
AI (no data in this column at this time)

**Table B** has columns:
PC (key)
 
CI (key)
CT
CS
CV
AI

I would like to update **Table A** so that A.AI = B.AI
The update statement I wrote is as follows:

```
     Update A
        Set A.AI *= B.AI
       From A, B
      where A.PC *= B.PC
        And A.CI *= B.CI
```

When I attempted to test this I used the SQL statement:

```
     Select A.*
       From A, B
      Where A.CI *= B.CI
      And A.PC *= B.PC
      And A.AI *= B.AI
      Group by A.AI, A.CI, A.PI;
```

And everything populates while the AI column remains empty. Can anyone help me realize my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo here:

```
Set A.AI *= B.AI
```

Should be:

```
Set A.AI = B.AI
```

Comment: Thanks! but that still doesn't explain why my second sql statement is returning the AI column completely blank.

Comment: I'm really not sure what the output of the the erroneous statement is.  To me it doesn't look like valid SQL (but clearly it runs)  My guess, though, is that the *= results in a null or blank value?

Comment: Try running the update as a select, and see what the output is (e.g. SELECT
        *= B.AI
       From A, B
      where A.PC *= B.PC
        And A.CI *= B.CI)